# HttpHandler in separate assembly always returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, httphandler, class-library

I have a created an httphandler in a separate assembly from my main application,so I can reuse the code elsewere.  Below is an example of the code I am using for the handler

```
namespace LifespeakCustomFields{
public class CustomFieldsHandler : IHttpHandler
{
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
 ....
```

In the web.config of my primary application (using mvc3, .net 4.5) I added the following entry to the  system.webserver element (I am using iis7 integrated mode)

```
 <handlers>
        <add name="CustomFieldsHandler" path="*.myhandler" verb="*" type="LifespeakCustomFields.CustomFieldsHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
```

This seems like the correct configuration, however when I make a request for this resource (/test.myhandler), it always returns a 404 error, even though it clearly exists. Not sure what the issue could be.

Comment: Likely you need to register ".myhandler" extension or make all requests go through ASP.Net - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4264256/477420

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.g. for this handler :

```
 <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="TestHandler" path="testhandler" type="ClassLibrary1.TestHandler,ClassLibrary1" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

but you also need to tell the ignore path to MVC route , in RouteConfig.cs:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("testhandler");
```

Comment: Thanks, the path was getting added to the mvc routes, so adding an ignoreroute directive fixed the problem. However, I had to use the following path  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.testhandler/{*pathInfo}"); so it would be properly ignored by the router.